# KDE Connect SMS - NEW-Button is not working

Tags: kde-plasma

The "New button" in "KDE Connect - SMS" is grayed out, although the smartphone is connected.

What can I do?

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaPD0.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Commence typing a name or number in the search box on the left,
choose person then enter, compose screen is then available.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Just type (or paste) the phone number in the top left box.
Once a number is in there, the +New button becomes available for you to click.

Just went through this myself on OpenSuSe and cellphone has successfully sent a number of SMS.